# What's the Meaning of "Remained Posters" in Following Sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of "remained posters" in the following sentence?

> "As long as a wine-garden owner and a shoemaker remained posters, life would be bearable."

Source: Half-Truths and One-and-a-Half Truths by Karl Kraus

Comment: You need more context to grasp the meaning.

Comment: No, this is a full sentence and the former and latter sentence doesn't add or connect any meanings to it.

Comment: I’d disagree with thar.

Comment: Since Kraus died in 1936 I assume it's nothing to do with online forums or message boards. The OED has a variety of meanings but none seems obviously relevant: someone who posts mail; someone who travels fast; someone who sticks up posters; a messenger.

Comment: @Xanne Yes, I was wrong, there was a hint in the following sentence, as mentioned by Jack O'Flaherty in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means they did not stop being *posters*, whatever being a *poster* means there.

*They refilled all the glasses. No glass remained empty.*

[Google Books *selected quote*](https://books.google.com/books?id=T9V0j2sfPpUC&pg=PA116&dq=%22As%20long%20as%20a%20wine-garden%20owner%20and%20a%20shoemaker%20remained%20posters,%20life%20would%20be%20bearable.%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7_ZS_x_P5AhUOmGoFHc0_DuAQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22As%20long%20as%20a%20wine-garden%20owner%20and%20a%20shoemaker%20remained%20posters%2C%20life%20would%20be%20bearable.%22&f=false)
"I am in pursuit of an idea that has just turned the corner - and someone cries "Ta-xi". **As long as a wine-garden owner and a shoemaker remained posters**, life would be bearable. Fine, we'll commit their faces to memory. **But suddenly, they stand before us in the flesh**, put their hands on our shoulders..."

**"Posters"** simply means **"posted pictures"**, as compared to real beings standing in front of us.

Comment: my concern is actually with "posters".